# Using visitors cpu or gpu by php?

Tags: php, hash, gpu, cpu

How can I write a php script that uses visitors cpu or gpu to do something for example guess a md5 hash?
Is it possible?
If no,what about python and cgi?

Answer (score 3):

PHP doesn't have ability to interact with CPU AND GPU of visitors. Since php is a server side language it runs in server and process data. MD5 hashes also processes in server by php. it uses server resources. All serer side languages runs in server and has nothing to do with your GPU AND CPU. You can use javascript instead. It runs in browser and use clients/visitors GPU and CPU.